# Unable to install vlc via command line

Tags: gnome-terminal, vlc, conky

I am trying to install vlc media player via terminal but its not working.I am using Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit.Please help.

here's what I did:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
[sudo] password for amol: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vlc
amol@ubuntu:~$ 

amol@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install conky-all
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package conky-all
amol@ubuntu:~$
```

I have tried to install conky-all via command line but it shows the same error.Conky-all pakage is not available in software center.I really need it.Somebody please help.

Answer (score 1):

Conky-all and vlc packages are available at universe repositories. You have to enable universe repository inorder to install these two packages,

```
 sudo add-apt-repository universe
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install vlc
 sudo apt-get install conky-all
```

Comment: amol@ubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
[sudo] password for amol: 
'universe' distribution component is already enabled for all sources.
amol@ubuntu:~$

Comment: universe is already enabled, so run from the second command.

Answer (score 0):

You may not have not a `sources.list` file containing the correct source link

- Visit [Ubuntu sources list generator](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/) and copy the generated text
- create a text file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and paste the links there and save it.
- open terminal and run this command

  ```
  sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
  ```

Now you can install any package